# Android :Injecting KeyEvents

Tags: android, linux, keyboard, android-input-method, key-events

I am working on a project which has two modules , server and client. 
Server will be running on OTT devices (Android based) as an background service and will be responsible to actuate/inject keyevents and client will be sending keyevents over wifi.
Now i am able to control single application which includes the Server service or I can say that i am able to control all those app which I have developed (using broadcast receiver , Instrumentation...etc).

Now i have to control other apps also , I mean I have to send the keyevents on global level
I have gone through several tutorials but still stuck at this.
Last thing which i need to try is to inject key events at low level using JNI but i am alien to JNI and low level linux subsystem !!

is there any other workaround ? any lead would be helpful 
Thanks :D

these are my logcat values :-

```
03-25 16:12:06.422: E/Key Value(7679): 343
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/JavaBinder(8556): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556): error in getService
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556): android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService(ServiceManagerNative.java:123)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative$1.create(ActivityManagerNative.java:1832)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative$1.create(ActivityManagerNative.java:1830)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.util.Singleton.get(Singleton.java:34)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.getDefault(ActivityManagerNative.java:74)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/ServiceManager(8556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556): java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:356)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:619)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.commands.input.Input.injectKeyEvent(Input.java:201)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.commands.input.Input.sendKeyEvent(Input.java:163)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.commands.input.Input.run(Input.java:64)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.commands.input.Input.main(Input.java:41)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
03-25 16:12:06.752: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556): Error reporting crash
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-25 16:12:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You will not be able to inject events unless you modify the security model of the devices or are the creator of the installed system image, or are doing so by means of something started via ADB.

Comment: @ChrisStratton
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/
i was following this link earlier , but i am not able to figure it out correctly